# What changes required for adhering the deadline for app updates for iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

Got an email from Apple about the deadline for an app update 
**for more info -** [link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03262020b)

What changes as a developer need to change in the code base for iOS13 SDK
I have changed the target and build the app, Its working fine apart from that do we have to implement 
signing with apple as mandatory changes for ios 13 to accommodate as per guideline

**Below are the things apple has sent on mail to cross-verify**

- Apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later and use an Xcode storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen.
- iPhone apps must support all iPhone screens and all iPad apps must support all iPad screens.
- Apps for Apple Watch must be built with the watchOS 6 SDK or later.
- Apps that authenticate or set up user accounts must support Sign in with Apple if required by guideline 4.8 of the App Store Review Guidelines.
- Apps in the Kids Category must be in full compliance with guideline 1.3 and guideline 5.1.4. of the App Store Review Guidelines.
- Apps using HTML 5 must be in full compliance with guideline 4.7 sections 4, 5, and 6 of the App Store Review Guidelines.

if someone has done do let us know what changes you have done.
Thank you

Comment: Just build with Xcode 11+.

Comment: @Sweeper apart from Xcode 11 build, do we need to implement sign-in with apple also ?

Comment: @Sweeper ok got it thanks

Comment: @Sweeper Any need to change any build settings in the project? For example, I currently have "iOS deployment target" set to "iOS 8.0" under "Runner/Build settings/Deployment" and "Runner/Info/Deployment target". Should/must I change this to iOS 13.0?

Comment: @MagnusW no nothing need to change apart from running the app on Xcode 11, and just check sign-in with apple if needed.

Comment: @AbdulKarim Check this section to know whether your app need to implement sign-in with apple. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple

It seems we need to implement sign-in with apple if our app supports third-party or social login service

Comment: @MagnusW  You are getting wrong. what you are talking it is the minimum deployment target, not an iOS 13 SDK. Just upload build from new Xcode and check if any part of your app is breaking or not..Especially UI. and one more thing you need to add launch screen storyboard instead of the traditional way to splash screen.

Comment: I got the same e-mail but still not sure about the last item regarding HTML5. Is that about web Views?

Comment: Does anyone know if we don't follow those guidelines if the apps will be removed? Or is that only for new apps and app updates?

Comment: @edgsv it wont be removed I guess but developers wont able to upload a new build after  June 30, 2020

Answer (score 1):

the message simply means that any developer looking to either release a new app or an update to an existing app on the App Store will have to build it using iOS 13 SDK.

If there is not proper need to update your app, then you can ignore the message !